# How do I hash a string in Racket?

Tags: hash, racket

How do I quickly get a hash of a string, using something like the hash function used in Racket's [hash tables](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`equal-hash-code`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._equal-hash-code))) function.

> ```
> (equal-hash-code v) → fixnum?
>   v : any/c
> ```

Examples:

```
> (equal-hash-code "apple")
176156759254714678
> (equal-hash-code "orange")
-3948353453564139403
```